# angular2 dynamically change the style property value

Tags: angular

I need to update a transform rotate value of image which dynamically change over the time

I tried something like below, but it isnt worked

`style="transform: rotate(imagerotation ? imagerotation : 0 + deg);"`

What is the proper way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
[style.transform]="'rotate(' + (imagerotation ? imagerotation : 0) + 'deg)'"
```